# How to check which submit button was pressed using JavaScript using .on function button tag

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form where i have two submit buttons

```
<button name="save" type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-danger">Save <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
<button name="send" type="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-danger">Send For Approval <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file"></span></button>
```

use the following to process in java-script

```
$('form#estimations').on('submit' ,function(){
    // my code
}
```

So depending on button press i want to have different code for each button but within the same function.

I have tried checking on stack overflow but most answers revolve around on click events but i am using .on functionality.

Comment: You'll most likely want to use `.on('click'` on the individual buttons that you want to be able to tell the difference between.

Comment: add an argument to `function()` ... because it is called with one anyway ... `function(e){
    console.log(e.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget.id);` ... no need to use click event instead that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the name of the button if you change to click

```
var name = $(this).attr("name");
```

Comment: I said if you change to click